# Odin3 says phone is successfully rooted but I have no root access

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, odin

I'm attempting to Root my Galaxy S3 to try and breath new life in to it (I don't want to upgrade if I don't have to).

I've followed the steps detailed in [this post](http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-phones/how-to-root-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-50008588/) and the results seemed to suggest that everything had worked, as you can see in the screen shot, however when I check using the [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freeandroidtools.root_checker) app it states -

> **Root Access** - no access

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't find anything that I can understand, so I'd be grateful if someone can help me fix this problem.

[image: Odin3 Success]

---

**Update**

Below are two screen shots taken after the above root process. On the left is the aforementioned Root Checker app, showing no access. And on the right is a warning shown when I open the SuperSU app.

I have indeed just updated to 4.3, so I'm guessing I'd need to go down the manually re-root app, but I have no idea what the relevant forum would be.

[image]

Comment: Did you try again from step 4 like the tutorial says in the end?

Comment: Yep, I've don't it 4 times now :(

Comment: Is it the international version or a carrier-modified version?

Comment: Carrier-modified (O2 in the UK).

Comment: Do you get to [this](http://galaxys3root.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/howto-root-galaxys3-jellybean-ics-8-690x467.jpg) screen? If not, uncheck auto reboot in odin, reflash, remove battery when done and enter recovery mode (VolUp+Home+Power), this will install root. See [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1957273) link for more details.

Comment: That screen shot is exactly what I get. I am looking in to the other link now though...

Comment: after flash autoroot, do you installed the latest version of SuperSu?

Answer (score 1):

looks like this pda file is only flashing recovery and cache image. So you should have a custom recovery now(probably CWM recovery).

If this is the case download supersu from here: http://download.chainfire.eu/396/SuperSU/ and push it onto your device.

After this boot into recovery(probably vol up + home + power) and install this supersu update zip.

Reboot system and see if you have luck :)